# Dynamically adding and removing segments from a track in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3

I want to display a track in real-time with OpenLayers 3 which disolves at the end, just like a snails trail.

Only appending new coordinates to a LineString is easy. See this [example](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch10-openlayers-goes-mobile/example-04.html). But removing coordinates from the end of the line does not seem to be supported by the API.

How should I go about that? Is extending the LineString class the only option? Or should I use a separate feature for each line segment?

**Update**:

I used this code with ol-debug.js. But get/setFlatCoordinates is not exported in the compiled version.

```
var flatCoordinates = geometry.getFlatCoordinates();  // not exported
if (flatCoordinates && flatCoordinates.length > 100) {
  // remove first coordinate elements from array
  flatCoordinates.splice(0, geometry.getStride());
  // call push with coordinate elements as arguments
  Array.prototype.push.apply(flatCoordinates, coordinate);
  // update coordinates calling change()
  geometry.setFlatCoordinates(geometry.getLayout(), flatCoordinates);
} 
else {
  geometry.appendCoordinate(coordinate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [appendCoordinate](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#appendCoordinate) method is a shortcut for the fairly common use case of adding a coordinate to the end of a LineString. To modify geometries with more control, set your desired coordinates with [setCoordinates](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#setCoordinates).

```
var maxCoords = 100;
var coords = lineString.getCoordinates(); // get coordinate array
coords.unshift(newCoord); // add to beginning of array
if (coords.length > maxCoords) {
    coords.length = maxCoords;
}
lineString.setCoordinates(coords);
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked this option as I wanted to avoid re-rendering of the whole line. But I guess that is also done with a simple append.

Comment: Yes. Anytime the geometry is modified, it is re-simplified (ol3 draws a simplified version of the geometry) and re-rendered. Also, any change event listeners will be triggered. This is regardless of if you are using appendCoordinate or setCoordinates. The overhead of using getCoordinates and setCoordinates instead of direct modification is the extra memory for the temporary coordinate array and the cpu cycles of inflating/deflating to/from the internal coordinate representation.

Comment: Thanks again. Does "simplified" also mean that line segments with zero distance (no movement) are removed? I am now filtering new coordinates that point to the same location as the previous one.

Comment: Yes, for each shown resolution, ol3 removes coordinates that would not visually alter the geometry to speed up rendering. That includes coordinates that are very close to each other or that are more or less on a straight line. 

The algorithm used (for linestrings) is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm 

So if your filtering is for performance reasons, it's probably unneccesary.

Comment: More specifically, ol3 will simplify your geometry so that the maximum diff between the simplified geometry and the drawn one is 0.5 pixels.

Also note that the simplification is entirely internal, if you call getCoordinates you always get the un-simplified coordinates.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.