# Openlayers 3: redrawing the map layer each time a segment is added to a LineString

Tags: canvas, render, openlayers-3

To follow up on

[Dynamically adding and removing segments from a track in OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411953/dynamically-adding-and-removing-segments-from-a-track-in-openlayers-3)

I am animating the drawing of a LineString segment by segment using a setInterval loop. I end up rerendering the layer each time I loop through the function and add a segment. Is the is most efficient way to do this? The code works, although I get an

```
AssertionError: Assertion failed: listeners already registered
```

error for each loop after the first.

Relevant code below:

```
    function makeLineString(multipointCoords) {

        var trackStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,255,0.2)',
                width: 0.5
            })
        });

        var trackFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([
                ol.proj.transform(multipointCoords[0][0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
            ])
        });

        var trackLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [trackFeature],
            }),
            style: trackStyle
        });

        var coordinate, i = 1,
            length = multipointCoords[0].length;
        var timeInterval = 250;
        console.log(i);

        var timer;
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            segmentConstruction(multipointCoords);
        }, timeInterval);

        function segmentConstruction(multipointCoords) {

            coordinate = ol.proj.transform(multipointCoords[0][i], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

            trackFeature.getGeometry().appendCoordinate(coordinate);

            if (i === length-1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                i++;
                map.addLayer(trackLayer);
            };
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't do this. You may want something like this:

```
var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString([
    ol.proj.fromLonLat(multipointCoords[0][0])
]);
var trackFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: lineString
});
```

And then your append function:

```
function segmentConstruction(multipointCoords) {

    coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat(multipointCoords[0][i]);
    lineString.appendCoordinate(coordinate);

    if (i === length-1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        i++;
        //map.addLayer(trackLayer); <----- remove this
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ots444of/

Comment: I amended my code per your advice, but the linestring is not rendering. Where in your code does the linestring or linestring segment render?

Comment: @interwebjill see fiddle demo. Your linestring is already on map. Every coordinate you append to it the library will render it for you.